# Accessing Mainframe Datasets using VFS in WSO2 ESB 6.1.1

Tags: wso2, mainframe, vfs

I am trying to access a Mainframe Dataset using VFS in WSO2 ESB 6.1.1

When I try fttping using command prompt I am able to download the dataset. But using the VFS,nothing happens when service is running.No logs printed,no error nothing.Below is the configuration I am using -

```
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:ftp://UsrName:password@hostname:port/'MMP7.FAST.V98KK.CMMS3ZMA.PSEUDO'</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">NONE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">*</parameter>
```

I am not sure if I am providing FileUri correctly.
Can anybody help me here? Is WSO2 capable of pulling data from mainframe directly or anything extra setting required to do so.